# White space not working properly

Tags: apex, visualforce

Removing white space between characters:

```
String s1 = 'Master Services Competency Cloud Management and Automation';
string s2=s1.trim();
String trimmed = s2.deleteWhitespace();
System.debug('---->'+trimmed);
```

In debug Log still It shows:

```
 MasterServicesCompetency CloudManagementandAutomation
```

Required Output:

```
 MasterServicesCompetencyCloudManagementandAutomation
```

Comment: I just tested your code and this is working fine for me.

Comment: even for me. Probably giving more info would help

Comment: This code works perfectly fine. I just tested in my developer console and it gives the expected result.

Comment: /**
String s1 = 'Master Services Competency Cloud Management and Automation';
string s2=s1.trim();
String trimmed = s2.deleteWhitespace();
System.debug('---->'+trimmed); 
**/

Comment: Note that the s1.trim() is unnecessary since deleteWhitespace also operates at the start and end of the string.